A function to read ASCII data files with 3*n columns
This C# 4.7.0 function works moderately well.
However, I need to increase the speed more. How can I do that?
Alternatively, can I start start exactly from the startRowNo without going through the skipping mechanism?
Note: You must not use any local IEnumerable to store temporary array/list.
    public static IEnumerable<Vec3> ReadVec3(string filePath, int chainIndex, int startRowNo, int endRowNo)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)))
        {
            string line;
            int currentRowNo = 0;

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                currentRowNo++;

                if (currentRowNo < startRowNo)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (currentRowNo > endRowNo)
                {
                    yield break;
                }

                string[] values = line.Split(new[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                if (values.Length == 0 || !double.TryParse(values[0], out _))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                int baseIndex = chainIndex * 3;
                if (values.Length > baseIndex + 2)
                {
                    double x = double.Parse(values[baseIndex]);
                    double y = double.Parse(values[baseIndex + 1]);
                    double z = double.Parse(values[baseIndex + 2]);
                    yield return new Vec3(x, y, z);
                }
            }
        }
    }

An example data-file with 15x3=45 columns.
#   r_end-X     r_end-Y    r_end-Z   r_end-X     r_end-Y    r_end-Z   r_end-X     r_end-Y    r_end-Z   r_end-X     r_end-Y    r_end-Z   r_end-X     r_end-Y    r_end-Z   r_end-X     r_end-Y    r_end-Z   r_end-X     r_end-Y    r_end-Z   r_end-X     r_end-Y    r_end-Z   r_end-X     r_end-Y    r_end-Z   r_end-X     r_end-Y    r_end-Z   r_end-X     r_end-Y    r_end-Z   r_end-X     r_end-Y    r_end-Z   r_end-X     r_end-Y    r_end-Z   r_end-X     r_end-Y    r_end-Z   r_end-X     r_end-Y    r_end-Z
29.645 6.522 13.566 22.470 17.178 15.205    6.589 11.778 28.236 0.288 -11.104 29.851    -17.345 8.979 25.737    14.427 -6.651 28.342    -9.189 -5.756 27.954    13.702 0.063 29.384 14.116 -15.585 20.996   1.599 -29.838 -9.982    17.211 -14.315 21.222   13.666 17.583 17.615    15.479 24.002 -1.287    17.308 23.768 9.989 -9.423 -3.982 29.059
28.991 7.431 13.983 23.681 16.220 13.784    3.232 13.397 28.537 3.068 -12.661 29.282    -16.350 12.224 25.648   13.778 -6.613 28.419    -10.457 -5.498 27.852   13.358 0.951 29.072 7.199 -13.925 25.069    -2.626 -28.391 -12.613  17.898 -11.044 23.968   16.668 18.298 15.517    15.834 23.813 -0.491    18.406 24.275 8.358 -12.870 -4.127 26.420
28.967 7.532 14.048 22.767 16.296 15.065    9.731 9.237 28.604  4.080 -11.765 29.654    -21.136 11.301 21.375   12.216 -4.589 28.843    -10.457 -5.498 27.852   14.759 -0.656 29.082    9.058 -11.031 26.370    -5.028 -28.251 -11.585  15.294 -12.207 24.839   16.771 19.500 14.645    19.198 20.534 -0.431    17.869 21.629 10.623    -12.016 -7.318 26.487
28.224 7.721 16.093 26.339 11.419 8.916 11.041 9.443 28.341 3.496 -8.000 30.378 -18.884 11.807 22.920   10.077 -6.265 29.623    -13.932 -7.189 24.983   13.828 -2.415 29.478    9.619 -8.538 26.652 -11.201 -24.925 -15.389 14.684 -10.225 24.933   18.554 19.025 10.582    18.690 22.189 -2.210    19.363 20.176 10.734    -10.844 1.116 26.333
27.692 -1.450 15.715    25.802 9.838 15.720 9.619 6.387 29.602  4.359 -6.099 30.746 -17.296 10.511 24.427   11.192 -5.068 29.380    -14.630 -3.598 24.970   15.109 -2.534 28.853    9.977 -9.989 26.621 -14.198 -23.346 -15.910 16.794 -9.818 22.966    16.754 20.060 10.851    15.042 19.825 -1.761    18.071 22.313 10.472    -15.294 -1.536 25.311
27.558 0.841 15.264 25.381 11.234 15.784    9.323 11.705 27.662 2.696 -2.023 27.806 -19.991 13.206 21.256   10.259 -5.534 29.848    -6.712 -6.608 25.571    16.019 -3.282 26.887    9.919 -9.882 26.632 -19.055 -17.538 -14.189 18.369 -6.661 23.347    16.601 20.416 7.170 18.723 15.056 6.072 16.318 24.159 8.512 -10.991 -3.680 26.924
27.745 0.655 15.045 25.505 10.074 16.313    2.615 12.708 28.706 7.974 -4.052 27.439 -16.105 12.723 22.491   10.398 -4.337 29.840    -7.527 -4.436 25.632    15.415 -4.318 27.780    10.694 -7.595 28.417    -22.104 -16.663 -10.804 18.369 -6.661 23.347    17.432 19.685 3.275 22.198 7.370 8.102  13.806 25.085 11.408    -11.890 -2.486 27.293

.
Program.cs
public class Vec3
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Z { get; set; }

    public Vec3(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"({X}, {Y}, {Z})";
    }
}

public class FileReaderMemoryLess
{
    public static IEnumerable<Vec3> ReadVec3(string filePath, int chainIndex, int startRowNo, int endRowNo)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)))
        {
            string line;
            int currentRowNo = 0;

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                currentRowNo++;

                if (currentRowNo < startRowNo)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (currentRowNo > endRowNo)
                {
                    yield break;
                }

                string[] values = line.Split(new[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                if (values.Length == 0 || !double.TryParse(values[0], out _))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                int baseIndex = chainIndex * 3;
                if (values.Length > baseIndex + 2)
                {
                    double x = double.Parse(values[baseIndex]);
                    double y = double.Parse(values[baseIndex + 1]);
                    double z = double.Parse(values[baseIndex + 2]);
                    yield return new Vec3(x, y, z);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// this driver program should read last two rows 
// of the last three columns in the given data file
// and then return two Vec3 objects as an IEnumerable<Vec3>
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Vec3ReaderExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filePath = "path_to_your_file.dat"; 
            int chainIndex = 14;  
            int skipRows = 5;
            int totalRowsCount = 7;  

            try
            {
                IEnumerable<Vec3> vec3Data = FileReaderMemoryLess.ReadVec3(filePath, chainIndex, skipRows+1, totalRowsCount-1);

                Console.WriteLine("Read the following Vec3 data:");
                foreach (var vec in vec3Data)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(vec);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error reading Vec3 data: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```


After the update, can you provide Vec3 and a sample test file, along with a Main?

Please add the targeted .NET version.

you could use Linq like values.TakeLast(3).Select(s => double.TryParse(s, out var x) ? x : 0).ToArray(); check Take and Skip and SkipLast and TakeLast extensions.

avoiding extra work

need to increase the speed more

When processing a given line, there's really just one place
that you're doing extra work: the line.Split() operation.
I would like to think an optimizing compiler would
hoist
the operation so we're not repeatedly allocating and freeing.
But still, you might try defining a two-element { ' ', '\t' }
array which the loop can make a reference to,
and see what your stopwatch says.
More significantly, you're definitely writing more values
entries than necessary.
There's an opportunity for early exit, especially
for a small chainIndex.
The file reading layer was already forced to scan for \n newline,
and has dragged those characters into L1 cache, so it's not like
there's much savings to be found there.
However, for a large chainIndex we might begin
at line length and scan backwards, ignoring the bulk of the line.
appropriate datastructure
binary format
If you do this a lot, and want it to be performant,
you should definitely serialize these free-form ASCII numbers
into a more sensible fixed-length binary format.
You don't need to allocate more memory,
but you should definitely allocated more disk space in the FS.
Then you'd be free to seek() along at your favorite stride,
reading out the results.
You could even have the writer flip column- / row-major order once,
for the benefit of multiple reader passes over the same data.
Or almost the same, writer could emit one new file for each
new chainIndex group of three columns.
row subset

start exactly from the startRowNo without going through the skipping mechanism?

See the remarks above about serializing to a convenient binary format.
Then you can exploit seek().
Suppose you don't do that.
Set K to 100 rows, or maybe 1000.
We will use tell() to figure out our current offset within the file.
Read through the file once, and every K-th line
output a (lineNo, offset) entry in the small index file you're building.
Hint: if the index file uses fixed-length entries,
perhaps in binary format, then you can binary search it
in \$O(\log n)\$ time.
When a reader wants to begin at startRowNo, it consults the
index for a less-than-or-equal lineNo, and seeks to there.
It now reads zero or more full lines until it's up to
the starting number, and then proceeds normally.
RDBMS
If you made a one-time pass over this text file and threw it into
a sqlite table, all of your initial concerns would have simply
disappeared. Prefer to use the right tool for the task at hand.
